# XML Digital Signature and Canonicalization

Tags: c#, xml, xml-dsig

Is it enough to just specify the canonicalization method to canonicalize the input xml as in

```
signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigExcC14NTransformUrl;
```

or should we also have to new up XmlDsigExcC14NTransform and add it as in

```
var reference = new Reference { Uri = ""};
reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
signedXml.AddReference(reference);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference on which elements the canonicalization algorithm is applied to. 
The canonicalization algorithm specified in *CanonicalizationMethod* is applied to the *SignedInfo* element of the signature node  and is used for the calculation of *SignatureValue*
A *Reference* with an empty URI addresses the node set of the XML resource containing the signature node, so the canonicalization algorithm specified in the *Transform* element of a reference is applied to this nodeset. In this case the canonicalization is used for the calculation of a *DigestValue*